# Solve the inequality $±x^n ± x^{n−1} ±···±x < 1/2 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math, factoring

Let n be an even positive integer. Prove that for any real number x there are at least
$2^{n/2}$ choices of the signs + and − such that
$±x^n ± x^{n−1} ±···±x < 1/2 $

Any tips/resources for solving such problems?

Comment: Well, for $|x|\geq1$ you have that $x^{2k}\geq x^{2k-1}$. Since $n$ is even, you can associate the summands in pairs $(\pm x^n\pm x^{n-1})+...+(\pm x^2\pm x)$. If for each pair we choose the $-$ sign for the first summand, then each parenthesis will be $\leq0$. So, we have $2^{n/2}$ for each choice of the sign of the second summand. For $|x|<1$ you can do it similarly.

Comment: You are going through the whole $2^n$ combinations there's bound to be some way in which you can abuse that without actually finding which combination satisfies it. Some sort of symmetry/anti-symmetry are often useful in such problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do much better than that. If a real number $a$ can be written as such a sum, then so can $-a$. Thus there are precisely $2^{n-1}$ combinations [i.e., half of the total $2^n$ combinations] so that the resulting sum is negative, which implies at least $2^{n-1} > 2^{n/2}$ combinations so that the resulting sum is smaller than $\frac{1}{2}$.